# How to update an attribute on a record after it has been loaded in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application a user can have a group with many alerts. When an alert is created it has an `t.boolean "read", default: false` attribute, which I want to set to true once the users has seen it.

I have the following:

**groups_controller.rb**

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @groups = current_user.groups.includes(:alerts, :new_alerts)
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
  <% group.alerts.limit(5).each do |alert| %>
     <% if alert.unread? %>
        <span class="badge pending-status">New</span>
     <% end %>
     ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in the **show.html.erb** on a group I show all the alerts.
I want to know if it's possible to mark those 5 in **index.html.erb** as read once they have been loaded into the view? So if I have 5 alerts and 3 are unread, I want the 3 to be shown as New, but once the page is refresh or **show.html.erb** is loaded, they will be shown an read.

Any suggestions?

I have been fiddling with an idea of having the read attribute as an integer instead, with a default of 0 and first time they are loaded `alert.update(read: 1)` and then alerts with `read > 2` would be the unread ones.

What do you think about that?

Comment: It can be done but it seems there will be a flaw in what you desire. You want the groups to be marked as soon as they are displayed? Suppose I press the F5 twice or refresh the page twice, displayed groups will be renewed instantly without being seen. Would that be okay?

Comment: @Fernand You are right, that could be an issue. However, I would rather have that flaw, than show "new" all the time. 

You have an idea for a solution without this flaw, or a hint to nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: my suggestion is like a read-button or something that once clicked will send an ajax to your controller and update the status.

Comment: but if you prefer the display: then filter the five groups in your controller, update their read-flag and then pass to view. Or... paging method using kaminari or will_paginate

Comment: @Fernand I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered that this would mark all the notifications belonging to a group as read for all users of the group? You're not scoping alerts by user id. Rather `group.alerts` just uses the `has_many :alerts` association.

Comment: Adding to @Fernand 's suggestion: better use AJAX to send a request to your controller when a user hovers over a notification or when the page has been loaded for x seconds (let x = 3). This will handle most of the side cases.